# Joomla System Requirements. Installing is freeezing

Tags: joomla

I uploaded joomla on my ftp when i start installation in first step i choose language then pressing next its showing wait bar in center screen and then nothing happens i waited 2 hours.

I tried Internet explorer, Chrome and Fire Fox

This is my system settings :

```
MySQL Version:
    5.0.91
Perl Version:
    5.8.8
PHP Version:
    5.2.12
```

Comment: We need more information than that. What version of Joomla are you installing? There is a whole list of server settings that would be useful to know. Is this XAMMP or a shared host or a dedicated server?

The software versions you list meet the minimum requirements (Perl is not required at all) but both your PHP and MySQL are pretty old, you should update on general principle.

Comment: I am facing the same problem right now! Just a loop on the loader. How was this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yoiu get a blank screen, or does it just freeze?
If you only get a blank screen, then this could be due to error reporting turned off on the webserver.